# Uncomment HTML code in Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I need to uncomment CSS code inside a style element (and I need to do this in Java).
Consider the following html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
   .big {
      font-size: 30px;
   }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Here is the desired result:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   .big {
      font-size: 30px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I usually use Jericho to do HTML parsing.

UPDATE. Solved:

```
String newHtmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("<style><!--", "<style>").replaceAll("--></style>", "</style>");
```

Comment: I assume you mean JavaScript.  You can't remove comments, but you can change classes on elements, or add css rules to elements -- which are cleaner options anyway.

Comment: I have not used Jericho, but I feel the parser cannot help you with this. Because once the parsing is complete, the commented code is ignored already. You may need to do some string manipulation before passing the content through Jericho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only comment in your file is CSS comment, you might consider something like :

```
    String html = ...; //HTML in String
    html.replaceAll("<!--", "");
    html.replaceAll("-->", "");
```